# 2-arguments function computing the order

Tags: functions, special-functions

I am seeking a function taking two positive integer inputs $a$ and $b$ where:

- $f(a,b)=1$ if $a>b$
- $f(a,b)=0$ if $a$ and $b$ are equal
- $f(a,b)=-1$ if $a<b$.

This function should use only simple operators (that is, no absolute value, no comparator $<$ and $>$, and no characteristic function).

Is this possible ?

Thank you.

Comment: $f(a,b)=a-b$....

Comment: @yanko Thank you. Indeed, there was an error in my post, otherwise this is obvious.

Comment: Well the function $f$ you want to find is the $f$ in my previous comment divided by the absolute value of $a-b$, so if you find a "simple" $f$ then the absolute value is also "simple" (as a product of two "simple" functions)  so I guess "that's not possible" (Am I make sense? - this question is hardly about mathematics so that's the best argument I have...)

Answer (score 1):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}$ The function you want is $\sgn(a-b)$ where $\sgn(x):\begin{cases}\dfrac x{|x|}& x\neq 0\\0& x=0\end{cases}\quad$ is the sign of $x$.

Note that $|x|$ can be defined as $\sqrt{x^2}$ without any "if".

The problem is that the value in $0$ is set arbitrary, so it cannot arise magically without using at least one if-related function (min, max, floor, characteristic function, heaviside, dirac, etc...).

The best you can hope for is an approximation, for instance $n\gg 1\quad f_n(a,b)=\dfrac{n(a-b)}{1+n\sqrt{(a-b)^2}}$

With $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(a,b)=\sgn(a-b)$

*Note: sometimes you would possibly see people using $0^x$ in place of $\begin{cases} 0 & x>0\\ 1&x=0\end{cases}$*

With this convention (far from being universally shared) then $f(a,b)=\dfrac{0^{|a-b|}+a-b}{0^{|a-b|}+|a-b|}-0^{|a-b|}$ would work.

You can see, that as soon as we accept a function that "embed" an if in its core definition (even if it is hidden) then there is no problem in defining another step function like $\sgn$.

*This may appear anecdotic but the C function `pow` actually displays this behaviour, so the $f$ above is perfectly computable.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you thing it is possible to avoid square roots and absolute values? In fact I'm seeking an expression relying only on simple functions. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If absolute value is disallowed, I think the best we can do is $$f(x) \approx \tanh (k(a-b))$$

where $k$ is a large number of your choosing, say $10^5$.

Comment: Thank you also for your answer.